# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when doing javax.imageio.ImageIO.read("filename")

Tags: java, eclipse, image

I want to compress the "JPG" images,which are about 4M or more.here is my codes:

```
public static void Compress(String sourceFolder,String destFolder,double proportion) throws IOException
{
    File source=new File(sourceFolder);
    File[] sourceFiles=null;
    if(source.isDirectory())
    {
        sourceFiles=source.listFiles();
        for(int i=0;i<sourceFiles.length;i++)
        {
            String name="";
            javax.imageio.ImageIO.setUseCache(false);
            Image src = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(sourceFiles[i]);
            name=sourceFiles[i].getName();
            int width=src.getWidth(null);
            int height=src.getHeight(null);
            destWidth=(int) (height*proportion);
            destHeight=(int) (width*proportion);
            BufferedImage tag=new BufferedImage(destWidth,destHeight,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics g = tag.getGraphics();  
            g.drawImage(src, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight, null);
            src.flush();
            src=null;
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destFolder+"/"+name);
            JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);  
            encoder.encode(tag);  
            out.close(); 
        }
    }
    else
        System.exit(0);
}
```

When it runs

```
Image src = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read("filename");
```

Exception occured:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.awt.image.DataBufferByte.<init>(DataBufferByte.java:58)
at java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.createDataBuffer(ComponentSampleModel.java:397)
at java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Raster.java:938)
at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createBufferedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:1056)
at javax.imageio.ImageReader.getDestination(ImageReader.java:2879)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:943)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:915)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1422)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1282)
at functions.CompressImage.Compress(CompressImage.java:50)
at functions.CompressImage.main(CompressImage.java:24)
```

I tried the run arguments(-Xms=1g),it still doesn't work!
Who knows the solution? Please help me,thank you!

Comment: did you try setting -Xmx (the max heap size)?

Comment: how many images? Or all together 4MB?

Comment: Just can you please note that -Xms=1g does not help if Xmx is less, second the syntax is -Xmx 1g,no semicolons or '='. And can you try to only read just the one file and do nothing, to see if throws the exception again. And make sure in the folder you don't have any sub folders and files other than the images.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get heap dump and analyze it. so the simplest way is to add JVM params like

```
 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

This will automatically create heap dump/ Later you can analyze what's wrong using java profilers(yourkit,jprofiler, etc)

Comment: did the application produced heap dump?

Comment: the point is that JVM will create heap dump automicatically for you - typically in the same directory where the JVM starts. please read this blog for details https://blogs.oracle.com/alanb/entry/heap_dumps_are_back_with

Comment: you should have something like this  java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -mn256m -mx512m ConsumeHeap
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid2262.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [531535128 bytes in 14.691 secs]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at ConsumeHeap$BigObject.(ConsumeHeap.java:22)
        at ConsumeHeap.main(ConsumeHeap.java:32)
$

Answer (score 0):

A 4MB JPG will result in a huge BitMap File. I think, it will just need a lot of memory. I ofte read about large memory-sonsumption in javax.imagio.

To get the bitmap size, calculate image_X * image_Y * (8 to 10 bit * 3(colors))

**update**
Some Math:

I assume 8bit per colorchannel:

7000 * 4900 * 8 * 3 = 1029000000 bit
                    = 122MB

I beleave, there has to be a byte[] of 122MB within the Memory. If the operating system (not the JVM) can't create that memory block, you'll get that exception.

Comment: the resolution of the image is about 4900*7000